# Really good quality Cooks Knifes

Tags: equipment, knives, shopping, knife-skills

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I look for in a good, multi-purpose chef's knife?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6158/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-good-multi-purpose-chefs-knife)

Hi guys

Just wondering what people consider to be the best Cooks knifes you can get?

I've been to a couple of shops and a lot of people are saying that you can't go past the Japanese Knifes... Specifically Kikuichi. The one I have had 3 different places try and sell me is the Kikuichi Gold Elite Damascus Gyuto 210mm - http://www.chefknivestogo.com/kigoelsugy21.html

So what do people think? Is this a good knife? For the money is there better out there?

Cheers
Anthony

Comment: what criteria are you using to judge "best," or are you looking for a list of criteria that define "best?"  Also, by cook's knife do you mean chef's knife?

Comment: Right; I think there are several interesting, objective, non-duplicate questions in here waiting to be asked. Looking forward to an updated version.

Comment: Hi vdh_ant. We have an existing topic that with objective criteria and answers that covers how to choose a Chef's Knife. The questions asked in your question "What is the best?", "Is this good?", and "Is there better?" are all subjective questions which don't have objective answers. Well, "Is this good?" is an exception, but the answer is yes.

Comment: There is a relevant meta discussion taking place here: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/138/are-questions-about-equipment-off-topic Your question does seem to fall into the category of "which is better X or Y?" (your Y is every other knife in existence).