# How can I sharpen my chef's knives at home?

Tags: equipment, knives, sharpening

I have a beautiful Calphalon chef's knife that has served me well for years. However, lately I've noticed that it is quite dull, and the blade slips sometimes when cutting tomatoes and onions. How can I sharpen it without spending a fortune?

Comment: see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/35500/67

Comment: @joe: I would even call it a duplicate.

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knives+sharpening - we have lots of information on this topic beyond the duplicate target